# Accidentally lost network manager

Tags: network-manager

On Ubuntu 14.04, the internet kept disconnecting. So, I decide to restore connection ability, but I am new to linux. I typed:

```
sudo apt-get purge network-manager
```

The wifi icon on the top right was disinterested and I left with no internet. Since I have lots of software installed on my machine, I don't want to reinstall ubuntu. What would be the cure in this situation?
FYI, I have another windows PC, so I can download.